# Richfaces 4.5.17 Menuitem action method not working

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

developers !!

I am migrating a web application from JEE5 to JEE7. My problem concerns to the presentation layer.

All the system pages are being migrated from RichFaces 3.3.3 to 4.5.17. I have been following the official migration guide ([https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration][1]), the Richfaces forum (https://developer.jboss.org/en/richfaces) and of course StackOverflow. But none has provided me a solution to my problem:

The app menu is built dinamically on the managedbean (not with tags on xhtml). It worked fine on RF 3.3.3, using the classes HtmlToolBar, HtmlDropDownMenu, HtmlMenuGroup and HtmlMenuItem. However, after migrating to the RF4 corresponding classes, **the MenuItem action method is not fired anymore**. **After the user clicks on the MenuItem, page refreshes and request is made to the current page itself, instead of the desired page.**

The migrated code follows below:

**ManagedBean**

```
package br.gov.serpro.sfitweb.ui.managedbean;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.richfaces.component.Mode;
import org.richfaces.component.UIDropDownMenu;
import org.richfaces.component.UIMenuGroup;
import org.richfaces.component.UIMenuItem;
import org.richfaces.component.UIToolbar;

import br.gov.serpro.sfitweb.bean.entity.Usuario;
import br.gov.serpro.sfitweb.bean.enums.Permissao;
import br.gov.serpro.sfitweb.context.ContextFinder;
import br.gov.serpro.sfitweb.context.SFITSecurityContext;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MenuMBTrecho implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private UIToolbar toolbar;

    public MenuMBTrecho() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        montarToolbar();
    }

    public void montarToolbar() {
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        this.toolbar = (UIToolbar) ctx.getApplication().createComponent(ctx, UIToolbar.COMPONENT_TYPE,
                "org.richfaces.ToolbarGroupRenderer");

        // log.debug("User" + secCtx.getUserPrincipal().getCpf());

        UIDropDownMenu menuPlanejamento = new UIDropDownMenu();
        menuPlanejamento.setLabel("Planejamento");
        boolean mostraMenu = false;

        ///////// Submenu PPA /////////
        boolean mostraSubMenuPPA = false;
        UIMenuGroup subMenuPPA = new UIMenuGroup();
        subMenuPPA.setLabel("PPA");

        UIMenuItem menuItem = new UIMenuItem();
        menuItem.setMode(Mode.ajax);
        menuItem.setLabel("Cadastrar período de PPA");
        ExpressionFactory factory = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
        ELContext ELCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
        menuItem.setActionExpression(
                factory.createMethodExpression(ELCtx, "#{ppaMB.listarPpas}", String.class, new Class[] {}));

        subMenuPPA.getChildren().add(menuItem);
    }

    public UIToolbar getToolbar() {
        return toolbar;
    }

    public void setToolbar(UIToolbar toolbar) {
        this.toolbar = toolbar;
    }

}
```

**menu.xhtml**

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:richext="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/richext"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

        <div id="menu">
            <h:form id="menuForm">          
                <rich:toolbar binding="#{menuMB.toolbar}"/>
            </h:form>
        </div>

    </ui:composition>
```

**common.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"      
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<f:view contentType="text/html">

    <h:head>
        <ui:include src="/public/pages/scriptTags.xhtml" />
    </h:head>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="#{configMB.context}/public/resources/styles/richfaces.css" />

    <h:body onload="ajustaAltura();"
        style="width:100%; padding:0px; margin: 0px; border-spacing: 0px;">

        <h:form id="principalMenu">

        <rich:messages globalOnly="false" errorClass="errorFatalMessage"
            fatalClass="errorFatalMessage" infoClass="infoMessage"
            warnClass="warnMessage" showSummary="true" showDetail="true">
        </rich:messages>

        <ui:insert name="top">
            <ui:include src="/public/pages/top.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
        <ui:insert name="header">
            <ui:include src="/public/pages/header.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
        <ui:insert name="menu">
            <ui:include src="/private/pages/menu.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>

        <div id="corpo" align="center">
            <rich:panel style="width: 97%;border:0">
                <ui:insert name="body" />
            </rich:panel>
        </div>
        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <ui:include src="/public/pages/footer.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</f:view>
</html>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

        <application>
            <resource-bundle>
                <base-name>br.gov.serpro.sfitweb.utils.MsgReaderUTF8</base-name>
                <var>msg</var>
            </resource-bundle>
        </application>

        <lifecycle>
            <phase-listener>br.gov.serpro.sfitweb.ui.MessagePhaseListener</phase-listener>
        </lifecycle>

        <application>
            <locale-config>
                <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            </locale-config>
            <resource-bundle>
                <base-name>com.example.faces.i18n.Text</base-name>
                <var>text</var>
            </resource-bundle>
        </application>

    </faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>sfitweb</display-name>
    <distributable />

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- parametros necessario para processar os JS internos do Richfaces https://developer.jboss.org/thread/203506 -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.richfaces.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/org.richfaces.resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tomahawk.taglib.xml;
            /WEB-INF/taglib/sfit.taglib.xml;</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- parametros do Richfaces 4 -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>wine</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>weblets.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>weblets-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-Upgrading 
        filtro do richfaces nao eh mais necessario no JSF 2 -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>20m</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<!--    <listener> -->
<!--        <listener-class>br.gov.serpro.sfitweb.context.SFITSecurityServletRequestListener</listener-class> -->
<!--    </listener> -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>net.java.dev.weblets.WebletsContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- WebService para consulta de permissoes -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Weblets Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.java.dev.weblets.WebletsServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ImageUploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>br.gov.serpro.sfitweb.utils.ImageUploadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ImageDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>br.gov.serpro.sfitweb.utils.ImageDownloadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PossuiPermissao</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Weblets Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/weblets/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ImageUploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/imageUpload</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ImageDownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/image</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PossuiPermissao</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/PossuiPermissao</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!-- Pages Configuration -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/public/pages/error/HTTP404.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/public/pages/error/HTTP500.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/public/pages/login.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/public/pages/error/global.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Please, any help that points me at least to the cause of this problem would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance !

William

Comment: If you have an issue with the @action you should show it (and say what it is supposed to do), the HTML parts are largely irrelevant.

Comment: hello Makhiel ! Thanks for the reply ! It does not matter what the action does since it is not being fired. The xhtml could be relevant because there are some issues with RF4 when for example, the tag </h:head> was not placed (this was causing RF4 not loading javascript). That's why I posted the xhtml files. Also, I have just posted the web.xml and faces-config. Thank you !

Comment: Ah, looks like you have nested forms, get rid of them. If that doesn't help try creating the menu manually and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it !

1.) Modified init() on ManagedBean:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        menuPlanejamento = (UIDropDownMenu)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createComponent(UIDropDownMenu.COMPONENT_TYPE);
}
```

2.) Added `menuItem.setMode(Mode.ajax)` on montarToolbar() method;

3.) Modified the xhtml page:

```
<div id="menu">
        <h:form id="menuForm">
            <rich:toolbar id="menuToolbar">
                <rich:dropDownMenu id="menuPlanejamento" binding="#{menuMB.menuPlanejamento}"/> 
            </rich:toolbar>
        </h:form>
    </div>
```

That's it !!